# map size getting zero and returning NULL

Tags: c++, data-structures

In below class I am calling function `Register` and adding value in map successfully. Then I am checking size and it is showing as 1 as expected. Now I an calling function `getServerObj` after some different operation and I get `table` content size is zero

```
 20 class LocalDNServer
 21 {
 22     map<string,serverdetails*> table;
 23
 24     LocalDNServer()
 25     {
 26     }
 27     static LocalDNServer* ins;
 28 public:
 29     ~LocalDNServer()
 30     {
 31     }
 32     static LocalDNServer* getIns()
 33     {
 34         if(NULL == ins)
 35             return new LocalDNServer();
 36         return ins;
 37     }
 38     bool Register(const string& url, serverdetails* pServer)
 39     {
 40         printf("Calling register\n");
 41         //table[url] = pServer;
 42         table.insert(make_pair(url,pServer));// = pServer;
 43          printf("Map size = %d\n", table.size());
 44     }
 45     serverdetails* getServerObj(const string& url)
 46     {
 47         printf("Map size @ func __FUNC__%s = %d\n", __FUNCTION__,table.size());
 48         serverdetails* pT = table.find(url)->second;
 49         printf("%s\n", (pT->ip).c_str());
 50         exit(0);
 51         //return table.find((string*)url.c_str())->second;
 52     }
 53 };
 54
 55 LocalDNServer* LocalDNServer::ins = NULL;
```

O/P of my program [code](https://github.com/debdipta/designpattern/tree/master/proxy):

```
[root@readcpp proxy]# g++ -g main.cpp -o test
[root@readcpp proxy]# ./test
Implementation of proxy design pattern
Calling register
Map size = 1
Map size @ func __FUNC__getServerObj = 0
Segmentation fault
[root@readcpp proxy]#
```

Can anyone just guide why this is happening? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might be a problem with your implementation of the singleton pattern.

`getIns()` doesn't store the allocated `LocalDNSServer`, so every time you call it, you get a new instance.

Fix:

```
static LocalDNServer* getIns() 
{
  if(NULL == ins)
    ins = new LocalDNServer();
  return ins;
}
```